# WSS from JavaScript to plain Java

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, websocket

I am trying to create a websocket connection from JavaScript code to a Java server. I have managed to do this with a unsecure ws connection, but because the website that I want to use this code on is a secure https side, I have to use a secure websocket.

I have spend quite some time on research trying to get this to work, however I can't figure out how to get them connected. I have absolutely no experience with stuff like keystores or ciphers, but I don't *need* that security, I don't want to send any sensitive data.

Anyways, here is what I've tried:

```java
SLLServerSocket server = (SSLServerSocket) SSLServerSocketFactory
        .getDefault().createServerSocket(1234);
SSLSocket client = (SSLSocket) server.accept();
```

with corresponding JavaScript code:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:1234")
socket.onopen = () => console.log("Connected");
socket.onmessage = m => console.log("Message received:", m);
```

Running this resulted in a `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No available authentication scheme` which I managed to fix by adding

```java
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.server.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Now I am getting the exception `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common`. I've done some research on that as well but whatever I find seems assume that a keystore or something is already there, which it is not for me. In fact I don't really know what encryption it should use, I did not find anything about that

To be fair, part of the problem may very well be that I don't know what to actually search for, but that is why I am asking. There are already articles about these exceptions I am showing, I know them, and they didn't help.

Comment: Don't reinvent the websocket wheel, use a library. There's an official websocket spec in JSR-356. In any JEE container it's already available. Otherwise, use https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/tyrus/ as implementation.

Comment: Sure, I could use a library - but part of this question is to actually understand how this works. A library would just hide away how it's actually done. When I got it to work, I may actually use a library for convenience and performance reasons, and finding a library should be as simple as a google search for "java websocket library", that's really not the issue here.